# How to access other pc if I don't have monitor and nothing preinstalled

Tags: windows, remote-access

I just bought a mini PC, and I don't have VGA cable for it. I connected it to the LAN network, and I can see the IP address and MAC address of this PC.

I think there is nothing pre-installed to connect it to my laptop trough the network and install Windows?

How can I access this computer remotely? Is it possible to connect to it somehow without anything installed on it?

I have seen [THIS](http://www.maxivista.com/download.htm) but I can't install this product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way to get this done would be to get hold of a monitor somehow, as @Shinrai already established.

If this is absolutely impossible, consider the Windows AIK, which can be used to create images for unattended installation.

For Windows 7:

- [Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349343(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5753)

For Windows Vista:

- [Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748933(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10333)